# MonoTouch Convert UTC time to American Eastern Standard Time

Tags: xamarin.ios

How to convert UTC time to American Eastern Standard Time zone.

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

I am getting exception at first line - TimeZoneNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "America/New_York" - see this [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for a complete zone list